# My CSS cursor does not seem to show on my page

Tags: html, css, mouse-cursor

I'm trying to add a cursor to my web page. I want it to show up on only one of my .css sheets only.

I've been trying to add this: http://pastie.org/7471470 pasting it at the bottom of my css page, but it seems to have no effect!

```html
    <style type="text/css">body, a, a:hover { cursor:url(http://i45.tinypic.com/zkl2l5.png), progress !important;}</style>
    <a href="http://jadore-moderncursors.tumblr.com"></a>
```

Is the code not meant for css maybe?

Answer (score -1):

How can you hover `a` element when you have not any text in `a` like:

```
<a href="http://jadore-moderncursors.tumblr.com"></a>
                                                 ^//need to add something
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3b5z758d/) here i have added text when you hover it then you can see custom cursor image.